# Alfresco ajax advanced search

Tags: alfresco

With alfresco advanced search form I would like to perform search by ajax and display the list of search results in the same page (without reloading the page).

Is it possible?

Is there a recommended way to do it?

Thank you in advance

Comment: You mean a search like in a metadata field? We've done the same as the search in folder. http://www.contezza.nl/store/p19/Alfresco_Share_Folder_Search.html

Comment: Thank you for your  answer Tahir.
But  this isn't what i want to do.  I want to searh (when search button is cliked) by ajax.

Answer (score 2):

So if I understand you clearly you don't want the page to reload.

Sure that's possible!

Do you start by hacking into the advanced search form or do you create a new page just for this is maybe the first question.

You can do it either way. Probably the latter is easier to maintain and less hacking and you can use a c*lient-site Library* of your preference.

If you want to keep the default form you just need to change the following files

- `advsearch.js`, the client-side YUI file which gets run on the form and does the submit
- `/alfresco/site-webscripts/org/alfresco/components/search/advsearch.get.html.ftl`, the html file which has all the div's etc. defined.

So change the client-side library to do the search directly to the repo, take a look at **search.js** and use the method.

Then define in your template the search results area from **search.get.html.ftl**.

So basically you're merging these 2 components into 1 big one.

Comment: Thank you again.
I tried another method. I would like to add search fields to the form. So I directly uses the search  result page. I'm adding fields to the form  displyaed in search result page. So what I have to do is retrieve the search criteria and send them during the search.
Is this a good approach?


To customize the form I use Aikau widgets. I met a problem I know not solve: I not use the DateTextBox component. This component is it not supported by the 5.0.d version?

Thank you again.

Comment: Look if you've got another question, create a new one. This is no forum :). You asked a question and people can answer. Now you're a step further. Now you've got a technical question so create a new one.